# Doxygen change sections order in the generated file

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Automatically generated documentation has Macros section almost on top. Many of my files have thousands of definitions. Is it possible to move it to the bottom of the sections?

I read about `SECTION_ORDER` but the documentation has no information about it.

Is it possible to change the order of the sections without changing the source file?
Do you know how `SECTION_ORDER` *doxyfile* option works (if exists of course)?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Where did you read about `SECTION_ORDER`? Doxygen has no setting called `SETTING_ORDER` and never had. Did you read up about "Customizing the output" (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy. You need to generate the XML layout file and modify it.